# Perl Regex Group capturing -- not capturing all the text in the group

Tags: regex, perl

I've got this Perl file where I'm attempting to print a certain element from an xml string if it has the attribute `tag = "915"`.  The problem is, instead of printing out the entire element, it only prints out `915`.
This is the file:

```
print(get_marc_datafield("<datafield tag=\"915\">RandomStuff</datafield>"), "915");

sub get_marc_datafield {
    my $xml = shift;
    my $value = shift;
    my $datafield = "";
    if($xml =~ m/.*(<datafield tag="$value".*<\/datafield>).*/) {
        $datafield = $1;
    }
    return $datafield;
}
```

This should print out `<datafield tag="915">RandomStuff</datafield>`

But instead it prints out `915`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  Am I implementing group capturing incorrectly?

Comment: Well, for one thing, you would be better off with a proper HTML parser.

Comment: Perhaps, but this should still be really simple to implement, and my mistake is probably a very simple one.  So HTML parser aside, what's wrong with my code, and what am I doing wrong with group capturing?

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with perl, but it looks to me like you didn't pass the parameter `915` to the function, and so, `$value` is not recognised by the regex, thus, you get only `print("915")` or something like that.

Comment: Spot on @Jerry. since the function didn't get its "$value' parameter, it does not match the regex and therefore returns nothing, which is printed, followed by the 915.

Comment: Yes, 915 is the second argument. But to print, not your function.

Comment: @SzG Oops.  Wow.  That was a really silly mistake on my part.  To think that this whole time, it was just misplaced parentheses on my method call!  Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parentheses confusion. You were passing only one argument to the function, and printing 2 things. The second was a literal `915`. Pass both parameters to the function, and print only one thing:

```
print get_marc_datafield("<datafield tag=\"915\">RandomStuff</datafield>", "915");
```

Comment: The conventional wisdom is that extra brackets help readability. I always strongly disagreed, and here is why.